# Adding custom button on jqGrid to open some other URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jqgrid

I am using jQgrid, but my requirements are like I need a custom button just beside the refresh button on the navigation panel of the grid to open some other URL. On click of that button the new URL should be opened in a new browser window.

Below is the code I have so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <title>jqGrid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var mydata = [
    { id : "01", "name" : "row one", age : "25", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "pune", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "02", "name" : "row two" , age : "26", "sex" : "female","Lname" : "row one", location: "Agra", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "03", "name" : "row one" , age : "27", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "Delhi", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "04", "name" : "row two", age : "28", "sex" : "female","Lname" : "row one", location: "Mumbai", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "05", "name" : "row one" , age : "29", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "Haidrabad", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "06", "name" : "row two" , age : "30", "sex" : "female","Lname" : "row one", location: "Chennai", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "07", "name" : "row one" , age : "31", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "Kolkatta", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "08", "name" : "row two" , age : "32", "sex" : "female","Lname" : "row one", location: "Chandigarh", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "09", "name" : "row one", age : "33", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "Bhopal", dob:"12oct" },
    { id : "10", "name" : "row two" , age : "34", "sex" : "female","Lname" : "row one", location: "Surat", dob:"12oct"},
    { id : "11", "name" : "row three", age : "35", "sex" : "male","Lname" : "row one", location: "Ahmadabad", dob:"12oct" }
    ];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                data: mydata, //insert data from the data object we created above
                datatype: 'local',
                colNames:['Id','Name', 'Age', 'Sex','Lastname', 'Location', 'DOB'], //define column names
                colModel:[
                {name:'id', index:'id', key: true, width:50},
                {name:'name', index:'name', width:100},
                {name:'age', index:'age', width:100},
                {name:'sex', index:'sex', width:100},
                {name:'Lname', index:'lname', width:100},
                {name:'location', index:'location', width:100},
                {name:'dob', index:'dob', width:100}
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 480,
                height: 150,
                rowNum: 8,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
            $('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
               {
                   edit: false,
                   add: false,
                   del: false,
                   search: false,
                   view: false,
                   refresh: true,                   
                   position: "left",
                   cloneToTop: false
            });
        });    
   </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) method and call [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method inside of `onClickButton` callback.